# What does this mean ? WARNING:root:'PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE' environment variable was not set

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, spark-koalas

I am working in Python on a Jupyter Notebook, and I got this warning:

`WARNING:root:'PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE' environment variable was not set.`

I tried to remove it, but I couldn't. I tried to set PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE to 1, as I saw on some forums but it didn't work.

Here is my code :

```
PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE=1
import databricks.koalas as ks
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import datetime
```

What's wrong with it ?

I am using spark and koalas.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to set environment variable, you should use `os`. Otherwise you're just setting the variable in Python, but it doesn't get exported to the environment.

```
import os
os.environ["PYARROW_IGNORE_TIMEZONE"] = "1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when I tried it, I got an error : TypeError: str expected, not int

Comment: @Ousen92i sorry, please put 1 in quotes